# FSX user designed panel L:var Get/Set

Tags: c#, c++, xml

Although I am new I look up almost all topic about Local Variable change that created by developers for panels with C# via simconnect or something like that.
As much as I understand I must make a .dll using C++ and execute_calculator_code. The problem that I am bad at not only C++ but also XML and creating sim models and gauge design. There are some where our forms Doug Dawson's Web Site include some .dll but I didn't include and use in C#.
I want to change developer designed switch position and I get their variable value with C#. 
For example:  `(L:Swbatt, bool)  1 or 0`

Please help me how can I control local variable via C#? If anybody has a .dll which created C++ usable with C# please share or help me.

Comment: Looks like you are using Microsoft Flight Simulator.  You need to create a c# Class Project which creates a dll.  The class will call execute_calculator_code  using DLLImport.

Comment: If you have any project or .dll for use in C# could you please share wit me. Thank yuo.

Comment: There are plenty of examples at www.pinvoke.net.  See following for one example : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFile

Comment: Tnx so much  to help me :)